# Adjective for "composed by trees" (mathematics)

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I am currently writing a mathematical article and we are considering some formulas given by a sum of terms that are "codified" (or maybe better, graphically represented) by trees (in the mathematical sense, a type of graphs; irrelevant for the question). I would like to find inspiration for the correct adjective for such formulas. My collaborator proposes **"tree-wise"** formulas. While this would not be so bad (the suffix *-wise* is often used in mathematics, also sometimes in places where it doesn't strictly belong), I think we can probably do better. What would be some possible adjectives indicating that an object is "made up by trees" that we could use in our context?

Comment: Maybe make something from the Latin "arbor".  Similar to when we use "chromatic" in relation to color.  Searching in MathSciNet I can find papers with "arborescent" and "arboricity" in their titles.  Even "arborified".

Comment: In English, the word tree is used as an adjective: tree structure, for example.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking for a purely mathematical usage, and belongs on the Mathematics.SE site.

Comment: For whatever it's worth, treelike data structures are commonly called _hierarchical_.

Answer (score 1):

"summation over a tree" or "tree-folding formulas" is what you are looking for.

In mathematics we have things like "optimization over a graph", meaning the optimization problem is defined in graph-like structures. Similarly, one can say that he is doing "summation over a tree", the reader will immediately understand the phrase.  If you want an adjective, "tree-folding" is a good candidate. To fold something means to make something into a compact form by iterating over the indices of its elements in a pre-defined fashion.
A "tree-folding formula" is a formula that is derived by folding trees (tree-like mathematical structures).

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider using *arboreous*, but I don't know if anyone uses that for math papers.

> Adjective: arboreous  aa(r)'bo-ree-us
>
> 1. Inhabiting or frequenting trees
>
>    "arboreous apes";
>
>    - arboreal, tree-living
> 2. Abounding in trees
>
>    "an arboreous landscape";
>
>    - arboraceous, woodsy, woody
>
> *3. Resembling a tree in form and branching structure*
>
> "arboreous coral found off the coast of Bermuda";
>
> - arboreal, arborescent, arboresque, arboriform, dendriform, dendroid, dendroidal, treelike, tree-shaped
>
> See also: branchy, wooded

https://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=arboreous

Answer (score 0):

Not all usages can be specified by single words - otherwise language would be reduced to single words. I would suggest that your phrase:

> can be graphically represented by trees

describes quite well what you are attempting.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest *treed*. The word is an adjective to be found in some dictionaries, it has sporadic use shown in Google ngram, and it has been used in mathematical articles, for example see

> [Canadian Journal of Mathematics](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=8aR0i1I2XB4C&pg=PA218&dq=%22treed%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi2mtPR3LHsAhXCilwKHYqSCxkQ6AEwAHoECAIQAg#v=onepage&q=%22treed%22&f=false)